# C solution for producer-consumer with only ONE semaphore

Tags: c, multithreading

Following Code solves ( I think) producer-consumer problem with two threads using only one semaphore.

```
sem_t sem; //init to 1
int arr[100];

void producer()
{
    while(;;) {
    sem_wait(sem)
    if it is fully filled {
        sem_post(sem);
    } else { 
        run 100 times and fill the items

        sem_post(sem);
    }
    sleep(2);   
    }
}

void consumer()
{
    while(;;) {
    sem_wait(sem)
    if it is empty {
        sem_post(sem);
    } else {
        run 100 times and read the items
        reset the start index to 0 so producer could fill again
        sem_post(sem);
    }
    sleep(2);   
    }
}

int main()
{
    //create thread 1 calling consumer
    //create thread 2 calling producer
}
```

Question is why two semaphores (empty and full) are used? Cant the problem be solved with one semaphore?

Comment: Well, your 'PC queue' has an extra contraint above that usually seen - you have to fill up the entire array before a consumer gets to process any data.

Comment: This solution seams suboptimal. If a producer finds a full queue it is going to sleep and retry in 2000 secs and a consumer exhibits the same behavior when encountered an empty queue. In practice multithreaded code relying on sleep almost never works reliably. If a sleep period is too large latency suffers and if it is too small you are effectively creating a busy wait.

Comment: Thanks for the question, it generated an interesting read here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem but that page mentions two scenarios, a) "An inadequate solution could result in a deadlock where both processes are waiting to be awakened." and b) "a less experienced programmer might come up with a solution shown below"... so I wonder if you have really solved a classic problem.

Comment: @NickZavaritsky prolly 2000 us, but still very poor performance overall compared with a 'conventional 2 semaphore + mutex' PC queue:(

Comment: It's not really a PC queue.  It's an array protected by a binary semaphore acting as a mutex.

Comment: @MartinJames In posix world sleep sleeps the specified number of seconds. We have also got the fancy nanosleep. This is probably irrelevant to the op question anyway :)

Comment: I got the point that people are making. Still either the producer/consumer will not be immediately signaled to process if one of them finishes its job when one semaphore and a sleep is involved. With two sems, immediately, which ever is blocked could go ahead once the other finishes its job.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you need two semaphores is that the producer cannot do anything when the "bin" or whatever the producer and consumer are sharing is full, but the consumer cannot do anything when the bin is empty.

Therefore, the producer needs to have a semaphore for full and the consumer one for empty.

Comment: I think that the single semaphore is merely being used as a mutex to protect the array.  It's not really a producer-consumer queue.

Comment: I was more answering in general about semaphores on producer consumer queues as I was in a hurry.  Now that I look back it seems you would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

> Question is why two semaphores (empty and full) are used? Cant the problem be solved with one semaphore?

Generally speaking, it is needed **two** some sort of **condition variables** (empty and full) to solve the problem. These variables used in `wait()` and `notify()` semantics.

One semaphore can be use as one of such variables in the given problem, so **two semaphores** are sufficient.

Another way is to use **two actual condition variables** with **single monitor/mutex** (see `Using monitors` section at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer–consumer_problem).

Your variant is similar to the last case, but you use busy-wait(`sleep 2`) instead of actual waiting on condition variable(`wait()`).

Comment: I agree with you. CPU cycles would be wasted if we busy-wait.